# Mod_Rewrite help to understand this expression

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^user/(\w{1,50})\-\-(\w{1,50})\-(\w{1,50})\.html users.php?name=$1 [L]
```

url looks like this

```
site.com/user/first-middle-last.html
```

for some reason variable $_GET['name'] inside users.php returns only first name part not entire first middle and last, how can i make it process full name into name var

Answer (score 3):

Your regex has 3 capturing groups:

```
^user/(\w{1,50})-(\w{1,50})-(\w{1,50})\.html
      \________/ \________/ \________/
          $1         $2         $3
```

`$1` is the first group capturing: `(\w{1,50})`. If you want the whole text, try:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(\w{1,50}-\w{1,50}-\w{1,50})\.html users.php?name=$1 [L]
                  \__________________________/
                              $1
```

In addition, note that you don't have to escape dashes (`-`) outside of character set (`[...]`), and you have two dashes between the first and second word.

If you need, you can have it both ways - capture each word and the whole name:

```
^user/((\w{1,50})-(\w{1,50})-(\w{1,50}))\.html
      |\________/ \________/ \________/|
      |    $2         $3         $4    |
      \________________________________/
                      $1
```

Answer (score 1):

Each `$n` references a parenthesized group.  In this case, `$1` represents the first `(\w{1,50})`; the rest is being trapped into `$2` and `$3`.  Assuming the double hyphen is in fact supposed to be mapped to a single one (this is not clear from your example), you probably want

```
RewriteRule ^user/(\w{1,50})\-\-(\w{1,50})\-(\w{1,50})\.html users.php?name=$1-$2-$3 [L]
```

If that was a mistake and you do want the entire `first--middle-last` expression being rewritten, then @Kobi's answer is more correct than cutting it up and re-joining.